# Cant use arrayRemove in Firestore. Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Cant see the problem in my code when trying to delete elements in array with "arrayRemove".

This is my code:

```
const getRef = firebase.firestore().collection('customers').doc('andreas');

const response = await getRef.get();  

console.log(response.data()); // answer { bookings: [ '123booking', '456booking' ] }


// then i'm trying to delete the element with value 123booking: 

let deleteRef = firebase.firestore().collection('customers').doc('andreas');

const removeRes = await deleteRef.update({
    bookings: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('123booking')
});
```

This is my error message:

> Error [FirebaseError]: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field bookings in document customers/andreas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are mixing up the use of the JS SDK and of the Admin SDK:

On one hand, you do

```
const getRef = firebase.firestore().collection('customers').doc('andreas');  // JS SDK
```

and on the other hand, you do

```
bookings: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('123booking')  // Admin SDK
```

---

If you are actually using the Admin SDK (refer to the question tags), you should do

```
const getRef = admin.firestore().collection('customers').doc('andreas');
```

---

On the other hand, if you are not using the Admin SDK, i.e. this code is executed in a web app, change the following line from

```
bookings: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('123booking')
```

to

```
bookings: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('123booking')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm new to Firebase and got confused going after the node doc and not web doc. Have a great day